# Angularjs directive changing ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm making a directive that mimics a `<select>`, but allows me more styling, but couldn't find any information on how to implement it using ng-model. Here's the directive:

```
.directive('customSelect', [function() {
        return {
            restrict:'EA',
            require: "ngModel",
            scope:{
                choices:"=",
                selected:"="
            },
            template:'\
                <div class="custom-select">\
                    <div class="label">{{ selected }}</div>\
                    <ul>\
                        <li data-ng-repeat="choice in choices" data-ng-click="ngModel = choice">{{ choice }}</li>\
                    </ul>\
                </div>',
            replace:true
        }
}])
```

How can I set ng-model from the click event on the `<li>` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `ngModel.$setViewValue`:

```
app.directive('customSelect', [function() {
        return {
            restrict:'EA',
            require: "?ngModel",
            scope:{
                choices:"=",
                selected:"@"
            },
            link:function(scope,element, attrs,ngModel){
              scope.select = function (choice){
                 ngModel.$setViewValue(choice);
              }
            },
            templateUrl:"template.html",
            replace:true
        }
}])
```

Template:

```
<div class="custom-select">
  <div class="label">{{ selected }}</div>
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="choice in choices" data-ng-click="select(choice)">{{ choice }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/gFdO5LdSdf3tIYiv9VCn?p=preview) (click on an item to see output)

Comment: the demo is not complete.

Comment: @StarsSky: ah, problem when saving, I'll create the demo again